# Add parameter at the end of the jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-deployment

I would like to provide some extra parameter to the last step of jenkins pipeline. This step is triggered manually but with "current parameters" of previous step in the pipeline.

Is this posible?

Comment: How are you implementing your pipeline? Using [tag:jenkins-pipeline]?

Answer (score -1):

I did not try. But this may be helpful.

1. install [Rebuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin)
2. In the last step of pipeline, build manual-triggered job with parameters. 
   In manual-triggered job, do not proceed.

   ```
   # in the script
   if(triggered by Jenkins pipeline) {
     exit;
   }
   ```
3. Next you can rebuild with the previous parameters.